# Need help in proving any countably universal model contains a countably saturated model

Tags: model-theory

I try to prove that a countably universal model $\mathfrak{B}$ must contain a countably saturated model. I believe it can be done by proving $\mathfrak{B}$ contains a countably homogeneous model because a countably homogeneous and universal model is countably saturated. To do this, I think it needs to construct an elementary chain of countably homogeneous models in $\mathfrak{B}$. But I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: It does not help to prove that $\mathfrak{B}$ contains an homogeneous structure. Certainly it does, but in general it may not be universal/saturated.

Answer (score 2):

I claim that ${\rm Th}(\mathfrak{B})$ is small, that is, it has countably many parameters-free types with finitely many variables.

In fact, any such type has to be realized in $\mathfrak{B}$ which is countable (the OP does not say that, I doubt the claim is true otherwise).

Small theories have countable saturated models. Such model embeds elementarily in $\mathfrak{B}$.

Comment: These are **parameter-free** types. Each single types is realized in some contabile model. As this models embeds in $\mathfrak B$ the types is realized also in $ \mathfrak B$.

Comment: How do you prove $\mathfrak{B}$ has countably many parameters-free types with finitely many variables?

Comment: I wrote this in the answer above, but I repeat it as it has gone unnoticed. We need to assume  $\mathfrak{B}$ countable (otherwise the claim is false, I believe). A countable model can only realize countably many types.

Comment: But the standard model of Peano Arithmetic is also countable, but it has uncountable many types.

Comment: You confuse finitely consistent types with realized types.

Comment: @EugeneZhang The point is that if $\mathfrak{B}$ is countably universal, then every type is realized by some finite tuple in $\mathfrak{B}$ (since every type is realized by some finite tuple $\overline{a}$ in some countable model $\mathfrak{A}$, and there is an elementary embedding $f\colon \mathfrak{A}\to \mathfrak{B}$, so $f(\overline{a})$ realizes this type in $\mathfrak{B}$). Now there are only countably many finite tuples in $\mathfrak{B}$, and each type is realized by some such tuples, so there are only countably many types.

Comment: By contrast, there are continuum-many types relative to the complete theory of $\mathbb{N}$, but only countably many of them are realized by finite tuples from $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: How do you prove that "only countably many of them are realized by finite tuples from $\Bbb{N}$?

Comment: @EugeneZhang Because there are only countably many finite tuples from  $\mathbb{N}$! This is the whole point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144932/discussion-between-eugene-zhang-and-alex-kruckman).